# soup.find(" table", {"caption":"blind"})

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, caption

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://companyinfo.stock.naver.com/v1/company/c1010001.aspx?cmp_cd=056190")
bsj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = bsj.find_all("table" , {"class" : "gHead01 all-width"}).
```

But the table's caption attribute is blind.

[image: The table.png]

What should i do to get the table?..

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. The `<caption>` element is the first child of the table.

You can pass a function to `BeautifulSoup.find` to return a tag matching a specified condition.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html5lib")

def table_having_caption_text(text):
    def query(tag):
        first_child = tag.next
        return (
             tag.name=="table" 
             and first_child.name == 'caption'
             and first_child.text == text
        )
    return query

print(
     soup.find(
        table_having_caption_text("Blind")
     )
)
```